# Imputation and nested cross-validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, missing-data, data-imputation, k-nearest-neighbour

I am planning to do a nested cross-validation analysis using regularized regression. The inner loop will be used for model tuning and the outer loop for model assessment (test set). Because some data are missing, I want to use KNN to impute missing data in the training set.

I am aware that I need the imputation model of the training data set to impute the missing data in the test data set to avoid overfitting and an overoptimistic estimate of my model performance.

I now have two questions:

1. Do I need to use the imputation model of the training data set to impute the missing data in the validation dataset which I use for model tuning? My gut feeling says yes.
2. Max Kuhn wrote in his book "Clinical Prediction modelling" that you should separate predictor ($X$) and outcome ($Y$) variables. I would therefore impute my missing data using $X$ only. However, If a predictor variable $X$ is highly correlated with $Y$ but no other variable I would not be able to use this information and would introduce noise in my variable if I impute data. Do I understand Max Kuhn correctly?